# Minecraft 1.8 maps not zooming out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have crafted a map in 1.8 survival, and when I right clicked on it in my hotbar, the entire map instantly filled with information. Before 1.8 I had to walk around before it filled. Also, when I surround the map with paper on a crafting table to zoom out, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map):

> Please note, shift-clicking to retrieve a zoomed-out map will cause
> the eight extra sheets of paper to be consumed, but the map will be
> unchanged. The data from the old map will not be carried over to the
> new one. This is Minecraft Bug [MC-87](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-87).

If you shift-clicked to retrieve the map, try retrieving it without shift-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on creative or survival when you right click the map? If your on creative then it will full the map up instantly. Try searching up the zoom out recipe on the minecraft wiki, they might of changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the entire map shows up instantly is a feature of Minecraft 1.8.
For the map not zooming out, do **not** use shift-click with the zoom-out recipe!

Answer (score 0):

According to [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#History), maps have a zoom level, which was fixed at 1:8 prior to snapshot 12w34a, but from 12w34b starts at 1:1 and can be increased up to 1:16 by re-crafting an existing map (which means it is 64 times smaller than before). And there's a [bug(MC-87)](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-87) where if you use shift click to zoom out a map does not apply correct zoom level. Make sure you are not holding shift while crafting.